# Getting the following error when copying some files from guest to host shared folder:. “cp: cannot create regular file ... Operation not permitted”

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

I have a Fedora virtual machine running on my Mac via VirtualBox with a shared folder.

When I try to copy files from a folder in my guest (Fedora) machine to the shared folder in my host (Mac) machine, I get the following error for specific file types (`.pack`, `.idx` files from `.git` directories, and some other files without an extension from `.git` directories):

> cp: cannot create regular file './.git/modules/system/objects/pack/pack-76a613db2d4b00g53c8739a7400e3a92e69fcbd9.idx': Operation not permitted

All of the other files were copied correctly.

Any idea on how to make it work with all types of files?

Comment: in my case I had to copy with `sudo cp`